# Exception CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument only published

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I developed a c# Web Application with Visual Studio

.NET Framework 4.5.2

This application reads an rpt file, set dataset and save exported pdf in a folder.

Debugging my program locally works perfectly (I installed the Crystal Report for Visual Studio)

Publishing my application and putting it on my server (Windows Server 2019) I get the "The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception" Exception.

I tryied do download the Runtime [from this page](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads)

I tryied to publish the application in 64bit CPU

In my application property I have these references:
[image]

but i get the same error.
I have no idea what I have to do now.

Can you help me?

Comment: did you install the runtime on the server? if so, which version?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you still looking for this,
But I would like to suggest (even though its an old enough question)

put **crystalreportviewers13** folder with your published project as well your IIS path 
(i.e. - in my PC its - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319).

If this does not help your scenario, let me know.

1) You have to put folder in your published app folder. 
i.e. my published website/webapp is named : Inventory, than, 
path for crystalreportviewers13 folder is : 

[image: Folder Path]

where *4_0_30319* is dotnet framework version.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I don't understand... I have to put the crystalreportviewers13 folder in wich folder? backend?